# Content Security Policy not blocking

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, content-security-policy

I am using spring boot and angular and I have the following content security policy

```
img-src 'none'; default-src 'none'; font-src 'none'; style-src 'none'; script-src 'none';
```

but inside the front end console i found that js files are loaded from other sites.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js";
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the policy is actually being served as a response header or meta tag on the page? And that it is Content-Security-Policy and not Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only?

Comment: After deploying backend and front end as war on application server, the blocking worked. but when I testing using intellji (development) it wasn't blocking anything.

Answer (score 0):

They worked fine when I deployed on tomcat.

because on my dev environment I had different setup for the backend and frontend.